# Ensure entries in ParserRule are comma separated

Tags: java, validation, grammar, xtext

I have written following ParserRule in my Xtext grammar file:

```
TestSpec:
'{'
    ......
    (('"my"' ':' myValue=(MySpec) (',' | '}'))?) &
    ......
'}'

MySpec:
'{'
(
(('"suffix"' ':' suffixValue=(STRING) (',')?)?) &
(('"prefix"' ':' prefixValue=(STRING) (',')?)?) &
(('"none"' ':' noneValue=(STRING) (',')?)?) &
)
'}';
```

Now in my Xtext editor, ***I want to ensure that the entries in "my" end with comma except the last one*** and it should give an error if comma is missing between say "suffix" and "prefix" like in following example entries:

```
"my": {
    "suffix": "testString"  ---> I want this to give an error for missing comma (,)
    "prefix": "prefixString",
    "none": "noneString"
}
```

**Solution:**
One solution that I thought of is to change the grammar to following:

```
MySpec:
'{'
(
(('"suffix"' ':' suffixValue=(STRING) (',' | '}'))?) &
(('"prefix"' ':' prefixValue=(STRING) (',' | '}'))?) &
(('"none"' ':' noneValue=(STRING) (',' | '}'))?) &
);
```

But I am not sure if this the preferred way of doing it. Is it possible to achieve this through Validations or some other more elegant ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered on [Xtext Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/766661/?srch=comma%20separated#msg_766661).
I opted to solve it by using following standard pattern for comma-separated lists:

```
List:
    listItems+=ListItem (',' listItems+=ListItem)*;
```